# Is there a way to call a function with parameters using #selector in Swift

Tags: swift, function, selector, inputaccessoryview

I have an array of `UIToolbar` items that show when an `inputField` becomes first responder.

```
//... code
toolBar.items = [
            UIBarButtonItem(title: "Button 1", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: #selector(myFunction))]

myInputField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
```

Is that possible to call `myFunction` from the above example with a parameter?

Something like...

```
... #selector(myFunction(someParameter)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to `UIButton`, parameters can be passed via the `tag` attribute of `UIBarButtonItem`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    let firstButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Button 1", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action: #selector(myFunction))
    let secondButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Button 2", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action: #selector(myFunction))
    firstButton.tag = 1
    secondButton.tag = 2
    toolBar.items = [ firstButton, secondButton ]
    toolBar.sizeToFit()
    textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
}

func myFunction(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    print("Tapped: \(sender.tag)")
}
```

Tapping a button prints the button's tag in this example:

```
Tapped: 1   // Tap button 1
Tapped: 2   // Tap button 2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.